# Amazon AWS + Varnish + varnish-devicedetect

Tags: amazon-web-services, varnish

Can somebody help setup this?

In my instance (RHEL), installed Varnish it work well. 
Then setup **varnish-devicedetect**,

```
 yum  list installed | grep varnish
 varnish.x86_64                        3.0.5-1.16.amzn1             @amzn-main
 varnish-libs.x86_64                   3.0.5-1.16.amzn1             @amzn-main
 varnish-release.noarch                4.0-3.el6                    installed
```

When I tried add any code example to defaul.vcl, Varnish fails to start. This code is OK:

```
 include "devicedetect.vcl";
 sub vcl_recv {
     call devicedetect;
 }
```

But after this Varnish fails to start:

```
 sub vcl_backend_response {
     if (bereq.http.X-UA-Device) {
         if (!beresp.http.Vary) { # no Vary at all
             set beresp.http.Vary = "X-UA-Device";
         } elsif (beresp.http.Vary !~ "X-UA-Device") { # add to existing Vary
             set beresp.http.Vary = beresp.http.Vary + ", X-UA-Device";
         }
     }
     # comment this out if you don't want the client to know your classification
     set beresp.http.X-UA-Device = bereq.http.X-UA-Device;
 }
```

Tried, even empty:

```
 sub vcl_backend_response {

 }
```

Caused same problem.
What I missed?

Answer (score 1):

It seems found answer: need use rules from Varnish ver. 3, used this set:

```
sub vcl_fetch {
    if (req.http.X-UA-Device) {
        if (!beresp.http.Vary) { # no Vary at all
            set beresp.http.Vary = "X-UA-Device";
        } elseif (beresp.http.Vary !~ "X-UA-Device") { # add to existing Vary
            set beresp.http.Vary = beresp.http.Vary + ", X-UA-Device";
        }
    }
    set beresp.http.X-UA-Device = req.http.X-UA-Device;
}
sub vcl_deliver {
    if ((req.http.X-UA-Device) && (resp.http.Vary)) {
        set resp.http.Vary = regsub(resp.http.Vary, "X-UA-Device", "User-Agent");
    }
}
```

Found here: https://www.varnish-cache.org/docs/3.0/tutorial/devicedetection.html

Answer (score 1):

You could have found the error by trying to compile your vcl:

`varnishd -C -f default.vcl` (or whatever the path is to your vcl file)

This will tell you if your vcl has valid syntax or not - which will let varnish start without failure.